# PHPUNIT как проверить количество вызовов метода

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Например у меня есть модели Team и Player. В модели Team есть метод который циклом вызывает метод со связанной модели Player.

```
  public function setBusy($busy)
    {
        foreach ($this->players as $player) {
            $player->setBusy($busy);
        }
    }
```

Как проверить в тесте сколько раз был вызван этот метод `$player->setBusy()` ?

Comment: А как массив `Player` попадает в `Team`?

Comment: Очень просто. Это Laravel. Массив Player попадает в Team по связи.

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь сеттер для `players`? Или может это public-поле? Может быть аргумент конструктора для начального задания коллекции `Player`?

Comment: Иными словами, чтобы **модульно** тестировать взаимодействие `Team`-`Player` вам нужно как-то подменить реальные объекты `Player` на моки. А для этого нужен какой-то способ "засунуть" `Player` внутрь `Team` (Без помощи ORM).

Answer (score 1):

В PHPUnit для этих целей существуют [моки](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects). А вот и пример их использования для тестирования вашего метода:

```
class TeamTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testSetBusy()
    {
        $player = $this->createMock(Player::class);
        $player->expects($this->once())
            ->method('setBusy')
            ->with(true);

        // То, каким образом вы передаете набор объектов "Player" объекту
        // "Team", зависит только от вашего кода. Я предполагаю, что вы
        // используете для этого аргумент конструктора.
        $team = new Team([$player]);
        $team->setBusy(true);
    }
}
```